# Теги в движке Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Можно ли на один игровой объект поставить два тега? Если можно, то как?

Comment: .........нельзя

Comment: всегда есть решение, сделай вложенный GameObject и второй тег выставить на нем. При проверке брать его ребенка(можно назвать там как-нибудь gameobject, SecondTag например). Добро пожаловать в "костыляндию")

Comment: Лучше уж сделать тэг агрегатор, который будет отвечать за определенную группу обьектов. А конкритизировать тип объекта уже через компоненты.